# Convert decimal HTML entities to unicode characters from string

Tags: javascript, unicode, html-entities

I have an extract html file from a comment system I have to use that looks like this:

```
<div>Plz say my name&amp;#128516;&amp;#9996;&amp;#127995;</div>
<div>Dose Amelia like donuts &amp;#127849;&amp;#127849;</div>
```

Obviously the part to note is all the emoji. I then pull that HTML file in using

```
var questionsfile = "comments.inc";
$.get(questionsfile, function(response) {
    $(".noquestions").replaceWith(response);
});
```

I used `.replace()` to convert it back to `&#9996;` but it now just outputs it as plain text. How do I make it so that the `response` output contains ✌🍩?

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace its `text` as its `html`, check the demo below

```js
var str = `<div>Plz say my name&amp;#128516;&amp;#9996;&amp;#127995;</div>
<div>Dose Amelia like donuts &amp;#127849;&amp;#127849;</div>`;

var $str = $( str );
$str.find( "div" ).each( function(){ //iterate each div
    $(this).text( $(this).html() ); //replace text with html
})

$(".noquestions").replaceWith(  $str );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="noquestions-wrapper">
  <div class="noquestions">
     assasd
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The text was just an example of what was in the `response` so I tried your suggestion like this 
`$(response).find("div").each( function(){ //iterate each div
    $(this).text( $(this).html() ); //replace text with html
})`
but it still just output the text in the browser.